# Manually remove host from MAMP PRO

Tags: mysql, apache, localhost, mamp

I've added a new host to MAMP PRO which I didn't put a disk location for and now MAMP won't start properly. I get the spinning loading icon next to MySQL and nothing next to Apache (not loading or the connected diamond).

I've been through the methods to make sure no other instances of SQL are running (activity monitor and through terminal).

I've convinced myself it's the new host without a disk location that's the problem - but because MAMP PRO doesn't allow any editing until it's loaded I can't delete the host or add a disk location.

Can I manually remove the host from MAMP PRO - I've removed it from the hosts file in etc/ but it still appears in MAMP PRO.

And will this fix the problem or am I looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have had the same problem since a couple of days and tried to find the answer online. No luck with that.

This is not an answer to how to manually remove hosts, but it did solve my identical issue which also occurred when I had added a host with no disk location.

After lots of trial and error I tested to edit the content of the mysql config template. I took a backup of the content and then deleted the lot. Saved, restarted, MAMP Pro informed me that a template I had changed had been updated and MySQL started up fine (with the template content restored) and have ever since. Yeay!

So, my solution was this:

1. Open MAMP (not pro), start servers. This will let you open MAMP Pro without mysql start spinning and locking the program down to changes.
2. Open MAMP Pro
3. Go into the menu -> 'File' | 'Edit template' | 'MySQL my.cnf' -> erase
       content (do a backup), save.
4. Shut down and MAMP and MAMP Pro, restart MAMP Pro.