# Mamp and virtual host

Tags: mamp

I have created a new host but I forget to add the disk location and then I press the apply button.
Now my Mamp pro is blocked on the mysql activation and I have no idea how to stop it to remove the host I inserted..

Can someone help me?

Comment: I have found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695699/manually-remove-host-from-mamp-pro

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, execute these commands to stop the running services:

```
/Applications/MAMP Pro/bin/stopApache.sh
/Applications/MAMP Pro/bin/stopMysql.sh
```

(I actually only use MAMP and not MAMP Pro, so I'm guessing your stopApache and stopMysql are in the MAMP Pro and not MAMP like mine.)

Comment: Unfortunatly it doen't work: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!

Comment: This works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695699/manually-remove-host-from-mamp-pro

Comment: Sweet! Now if only there were reputation for helping out, heh ;)